# S3 maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, amazon-s3

I don't quite figure out which dependency to add in order to connect to S3.

I mean, currently, I'm using this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.282</version>
</dependency>
```

However, I'm missing `GetObjectRequest.Builder` class.

Currently, I'm building `GetObjectRequest` object using this code:

```java
S3Object object = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, keyDoc));
```

Where is located this class?

How many library are there in order to connect to S3?